# Вывод string в Python на несколько строк

Tags: python, строки

У меня задание, чтобы функция выдавала **одну** длинную **строку** с символами. Программа тестировщик однако ожидает при печати вывод на несколько рядов. 
Пример строки которую выдает моя функция (правильно):

```
    #        #        #       # #      # #      # #     #   #    #   #    #   #   #     #  #     #  #     # #############################     ####     ###       ## #   # ## #   # ##       ##  # #  ##  # #  ##       ##   #   ##   #   ##       ##  # #  ##  # #  ##       ## #   # ## #   # ##       ###     ####     ###       ############################
```

То что после печати ожидает программа тестировщик (от меня не зависит) - см. [фото](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nElBg.jpg).

Как я могу делать `return` в функции, чтобы соблюдалось описанное условие и программа тестировщик приняла программу?

Я бы мог сам напечатать легко через цикл, но по заданию именно функция должна возвращать одну строку. Программа тестировщик уже сама производит печать.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Используйте перенос строки. Пример: `print('## \n ##')`

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно отобразить рисунок из `#` затронув всего 1 строчку кода. Это вы можете сделать с помощью переноса строки `\n`.
Пример:

```
print("Очень\nХочу\nПить!")
```

Вывод:

```
Очень
Хочу
Пить!
```

И если важно -  `\n` можно использовать слитно с вашим текстом. Это никак не повлияет на отображение.